# Transparent image has background

Tags: html, css, image, transparency

logo.png is a transparent image. But when the web browser loads the web page, it has an invisible square around it. I only want the image to change when I am actually hovering over it, like on the apple website. I am sorry if the HTML is formatted weird here, I am not familiar with stackoverflow's system.

```css
.header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        padding: 20px 10px;
      }

      .header a {
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 25px;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }

      .header a.logo {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      .header a.logo img {
        width: 25%;
        height: 25%;
        transition: filter 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }

      .header a.logo:hover img {
        filter: brightness(1.2);
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        .header {
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: flex-start;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="header">
<a href="#home" class="logo">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAHg5.png" alt="SYMBL logo" onclick="show('home', 'contact')">
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 'It has an invisible square round it' - could you describe what that means - as I assume it is in some measure visible? Also if you could make your code into a runnable snippet, with a png which we can load that would be helpful. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Agreed, just need to see what the image and running code would look like.

Comment: Really sorry about that, didn't know. I updated it so you can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You are adding hover action to the red box which belongs to the link element. Instead add it to black box which belongs to img element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7MFe.png)

Instead, give class to your image, say `img_link` and apply css to it:

```
.img_link:hover {
    filter: brightness(1.2);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you added `background-color: #f1f1f1;` to header if you need transparent background with only image which change on hover.

```css
.header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
       
        padding: 20px 10px;
      }

      .header a {
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 25px;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }

      .header a.logo {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      .header a.logo img {
        width: 25%;
        height: 25%;
        transition: filter 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }

      .header a.logo:hover img {
        filter: brightness(1.2);
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        .header {
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: flex-start;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="header">
<a href="#home" class="logo">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAHg5.png" alt="SYMBL logo" onclick="show('home', 'contact')">
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        padding: 20px 10px;
      }

      .header a {
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 25px;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }

      .header a.logo {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      .header a.logo img {
        width: 25%;
        height: 25%;
        transition: filter 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }

      .header a.logo:hover img {
        filter: brightness(1.2);
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        .header {
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: flex-start;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="header">
<a href="#home" class="logo">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAHg5.png" alt="SYMBL logo" onclick="show('home', 'contact')">
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).